Minecraft TCP Socket Connection
I'm trying to make a MITM to check the packages passed between the Minecraft client and server, but I'm having a bit of a problem.
There doesn't seem to be any connection problems. I'm passing a proxy locally on the client and trying to connect by forcing the traffic to pass through it. The client responds normally, but there's no response from the server, and the client ends up disconnecting due to the lack of response from the server.
import socket
from threading import Thread


class Proxy2Server(Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        super(Proxy2Server, self).__init__()
        self.game = None
        self.port = port
        self.host = host
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.connect((host, port))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.server.recv(4096 * 8 * 8 * 8)

            if len(data) == 0:
                print("Server Close the Connection")
                break

            self.game.send(data)
            print(f"Server Data: {data}")

class Game2Proxy(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Game2Proxy, self).__init__()
        self.server = None

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.game.recv(4096 * 8 * 8 * 8)

            if len(data) == 0:
                print("Game Close the Connection")
                break

            self.server.send(data)
            print(f"Game Data: {data}")

class Proxy(Thread):
    def __init__(self, from_host, to_host, target_port, listen_port):
        super(Proxy, self).__init__()
        self.from_host = from_host
        self.to_host = to_host
        self.target_port = target_port
        self.listen_port = listen_port

    def run(self):

        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind((self.from_host, self.listen_port))
        sock.listen(5)

        print(f"Proxy Listening in {self.listen_port}")

        while True:
            self.g2p = Game2Proxy()
            self.p2s = Proxy2Server(self.to_host, self.target_port)

            self.g2p.server = self.p2s.server

            connection, addr = sock.accept()
            self.p2s.game = connection
            self.g2p.game = connection

            print(f'Accepted connection from {addr[0]}:{addr[1]}')

            self.g2p.start() 
            self.p2s.start()

master_server = Proxy('0.0.0.0', '0.0.0.0', 25565, 5555)
master_server.start() 

Output:


Aside: super(Game2Proxy, self) syntax isn't needed in Python 3. Just write super().

@GabrielJungles Do not include solution to question please (post a separate answer instead).

There isn't really a reason to post an image of the output. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

maybe you could check it with some existing proxy server like CharlesProxy And if you get some information then you can use them to create own program

Small nitpick - your proxy is connecting to the game server before a client has connected to the proxy. You should wait for the client to connect to the proxy first, then connect the proxy to the server, then start your threads to pass data back and forth between them
